# Why can't a ng-controller div contain a ng-href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

When putting a `data-ng-href` inside of a `data-ng-controller` the `data-ng-href` seems to stop working. **Why and how can I fix this?**

This works:

```
<div class="container">
    <a data-ng-href="/signout">sign out</a>
</div>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="myWorkingController">
    <a data-ng-href="/signout">sign out</a>
</div>
```

Comment: There must be something else going on here. Can you provide a minimal, reproducable example? Btw, you do realize that there is no point in using ng-href over href if the value is static? And have you checked the console log for errors?

Comment: Not sure why do you need `ng-href` when its value is constant.

Comment: @popovitsj ***Nothing*** else is going on, my code runs perfectly otherwise. This is the only div I have also and my controller is empty! No log errors!

Comment: Create a demo that replicates this

Comment: @raina77ow How would suggest I do otherwise, I want the browser to do a GET and refresh the entire browser (yes not SPA I know).

Comment: @charlietfl Demo is up and working. It seems to not have an issue online, it does however not work on my localhost?

Comment: I am unable to replicate this on Codepen.

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal Found the issue, answer posted.

Comment: @raina77ow Can you elaborate? What would be good practice for it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I DID IT. I found out why it wasn't working. I has to do with the controller dependency injections.

Does not work:

```
.controller('exampleCtrl', ['$location', function ($location) {}])
```

Works:

```
.controller('exampleCtrl', [ function () {}])
```

When reading the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) on the specific thing it states:

> What does it not do? 
>   It does not cause a full page reload when the
>   browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use
>   the lower-level API, $window.location.href.

**So, I can't use `data-ng-href` to redirect the browser if I'm injecting `$location`, simple.**